# what's the boost::type definition?

Tags: c++, boost

```
struct F
{
    int operator()(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
    bool operator()(long a, long b) { return a == b; }
};

F f;

int x = 104;

bind<int>(f, _1, _1)(x);        // f(x, x), i.e. zero
```

Some compilers have trouble with the bind(f, ...) syntax. For portability reasons, an alternative way to express the above is supported:

```
boost::bind(boost::type<int>(), f, _1, _1)(x);
```

like above, the code use a boost::type for function object type, 
**I  to know where contain the boost::type implementation?**

Comment: The second result of me searching "boost::type" was http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/type.hpp

Comment: yes, I search the src file, the result is same to you, but type.hpp just give me a blank templete struct, I think the struct implement operator () at least.

Comment: That's not `operator()`, that's a constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found the definition below.

```
// type.hpp
namespace boost {
  // Just a simple "type envelope". Useful in various contexts, mostly to work
  // around some MSVC deficiencies.
  template <class T>
  struct type {};
}
```

Comment: Reading the comment, it seems that any specialized struct can be used instead of the underlying type when MSVC, for instance, is used in certain situations. The situations are not clearly made known though.